# Rspec: should_receive on an instance class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rr

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
    @user.stub!(:must_not_be_in_somewhere).and_return(true)
 end

it "should send a email if we are 2 weeks from last email" do
    User.any_instance.should_receive(:deliver_promo_code).exactly(111).times

    post :create, :user => @user.attributes, :format => :json
 end
```

The code works but the test is not failing when it should...
Anyone has an idea of what is wrong with that code?

Comment: How should it be failing ( and why)?

Comment: because the method deliver_promo_code is called only once on the controller.

Comment: If no ShipMate::User object ever receives `deliver_promo_code`, then no failure will happen. I suspect that this is what's happening. Perhaps your code is going through a logic path (such as going through an `else` in an if-statement) that doesn't end up calling `deliver_promo_code`?